# UbuntuOnWindows: Restoring backup directory causes UbuntuOnWindows to fail starting

Tags: windows, windows-10

To be able to restore my Ubuntu-On-Windows in case of an emergency, I wanted to back up its directory that is for me located at

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

I store the entire directory as zip file.

Now when I restore this directory, Ubuntu first says "Updating Linux sub system", and then quits.

When I try to start UbuntuOnWindows again, it closes immediately.

How could I investigate what's going wrong here? I haven't been able to find a log file that would tell me more.

Or if anybody has already experienced this and found a solution, I'd be glad to hear about it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using a Windows program to restore to Ubuntu will corrupt it. You can only use Linux restore programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this blog: [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) and many others explicitly state, if you use a Windows program to create or modify files in Ubuntu on Windows they will become corrupted. You must use a Linux program to copy, restore or modify files within Ubuntu for Windows.

I suspect you used a Windows program to restore the `.zip` file and not a Linux program like one of those found here: [Zipping and Unzipping Files in UNIX](https://www.hostingmanual.net/zipping-unzipping-files-unix/)